# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in if statement

Tags: java

I am getting the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28
    at assignment.assgn1.main(assgn1.java:44)
```

I would be very grateful if someone could point out the error

```
    package assignment;

    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class assgn1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    try{

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("E:/AviationData.txt"),'\t','\n');
        PrintWriter NYreports = new PrintWriter("E:/NYReports.txt");
        String [] nextLine;
        int x;
        int sum=0;
        double totalFatal=0;
        Integer largest = 0;
        Integer smallest = 0;
        String [] token = null;
        //read first line, but it will not be counted with the rest of the records
        nextLine = csvReader.readNext();
        //create a map for unique Broad Phase in flight fields
        Map<String, Integer> broadPhase = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        //create an array list that will take in integer values of Fatal Injuries
        ArrayList <Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) !=null){
            sum++;

            String field = nextLine[0];
            //using regex values!
            token = field.split("\\s\\|\\s");
//for (String s: token){
//System.out.println(s);
//}
 if(token[28].equals(" ")){
broadPhase.put(token[28],0);
 }
  if(!token[28].equals(" ") && !token[28].equals("")){
broadPhase.put(token[28], 1);
 }

   //search for Fatal Injury values
   if(!token[23].isEmpty()){

  x=Integer.parseInt(token[23]);
  //add to ArrayList
   intList.add(x);
   totalFatal = x + totalFatal;
   }

    if(token[4].contains(", NY") && token[5].contains("/2015")){

 NYreports.println(nextLine[0]);


    }

        }

                for(int i =0; i<intList.size()-1; i++){
                if (intList.get(i) > largest);
                largest = intList.get(i);
                 if (intList.get(i)< smallest)
                smallest = intList.get(i);
                }

                System.out.println("There are " + sum + " records");

                System.out.println("There are " + (broadPhase.size())+" unique values in Broad Phase of Flight");
                 totalFatal = (totalFatal/sum);
                 System.out.println(largest + " is the largest number of Fatal injuries");
                 System.out.println("The average of Fatal injuries is " + totalFatal);
            NYreports.close();
            csvReader.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("File not Found");
    }
}
```

}

the error is on the line where if(token[28].equals(" ")){. is written.
what can i change to avoid it. also if any change in method used by me can be done.

Comment: It simply means that the 29th entry in your `token` array does not exist. Remember thay array indices start at 0.

Comment: before accesing a certain index from an array do a length check

Answer (score 0):

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException generally occurs when you try to access
>   an index which is not present on the array

, ie.. index > length - 1 (since arrays in java are 0 based).

To avoid this error make sure that you use only valid indexes , which are

> 0 =< idx < length.

In the current context you may want to add an additional check to ensure that array contains that index along with the normal if conditions.

something like

```
if(token.length > 28 && token[28].equals(" ")){
   broadPhase.put(token[28],0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `token[28]` doesn't exist. In other words, your `split()` call is returning an array that isn't as long as you think it is. I would check your input to see whether or not your input is correct.

On a side note, your method seems to be very... rough and hard coded. Assuming that you know the exact order the tokens are stored in, a better way to do this that would avoid the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception` is to loop through your tokens array using a either a for each loop or a normal for loop.

You can then parse each section while you're looping through it.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    // based on the i value, parse a different way
}
```